# How to update this query without looping or cursor in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

```
update a_program
set total_paguindikatif_rkpd = (select sum(isnull(pagu_dana_rkpd, 0))
                                from a_kegiatan
                                where id_prog = @id_prog 
                                  and is_deleted = 0 
                                  and id_jenisanggaran = 2 
                                  and status in(1,3,7,9)
                                ), 
    total_paguindikatif_kuappas = (select sum(isnull(pagu_dana_kuappas, 0))
                                   from a_kegiatan
                                   where id_prog = @id_prog 
                                     and is_deleted = 0 
                                     and id_jenisanggaran = 2 
                                     and status in(1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10)
                                    )
where 
    id_prog = @id_prog and id_jenisanggaran = 2;
```

That's my query. I want to automatically update without `loop` @id_prog to that query. How can I do this?

Thanks for helping me.. :)

Comment: Just as an aside - you should consider carefully whether you need to *store* these columns at all. In general, prefer not to store *derived* data - data that can be calculated from other data - unless you have a specific performance need (and even then, prefer to use built in functionality, such as indexed views which maintain the derived data automatically). Otherwise, you're just introducing an opportunity for the derived data to be out of date/inconsistent with reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update a set
    total_paguindikatif_rkpd = (select sum(isnull(pagu_dana_rkpd, 0))
                                from a_kegiatan
                                where id_prog = a.id_prog ---<<<
                                  and is_deleted = 0 
                                  and id_jenisanggaran = 2 
                                  and status in(1,3,7,9)
                                ), 
    total_paguindikatif_kuappas = (select sum(isnull(pagu_dana_kuappas, 0))
                                   from a_kegiatan
                                   where id_prog = a.id_prog ---<<<
                                     and is_deleted = 0 
                                     and id_jenisanggaran = 2 
                                     and status in(1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10)
                                    )
from a_program a
where a.id_jenisanggaran = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan Starostin :)
I'll try.. Honestly, I just wondering to the answer :D